# How to avoid multiple negatives in sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, past-tense, multiple-negation

I have written few lines, but I feel those could be more better in English, even I am not sure about grammatical mistakes. Please correct my below sentences

> "But that didn't go well as I didn't here back from you."
>       "I spoke few things which wasn't that impressive though that wasn't poor as well."

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <s>But that didn't go well as I didn't here back from you.</s>

As a general rule, don't start a sentence with "but" as it is a *conjunction*. Your spelling of "hear" is incorrect. Also as it appears this is a statement of logic that one thing follows another I think it should be:

> "*That can't* have gone well as I didn't **hear** back from you".

---

> <s>I spoke few things which wasn't that impressive though that wasn't poor as well.</s>

Some problems with pluralisation and restrictive/non-restrictive clauses need correcting. I think you mean:

> I **said** a few things **that weren't** that impressive, but **were not poor either**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second sentence you really made awesome. Still in the first sentence we have two negatives. Just saying.

Comment: @Arvindraja You're right, I have revised it, I think I understand it a bit better. Is this now more what you want to say?

Comment: Yeah seems ok now. However in this situation negatives can't be avoided. Because both sentences are dependent. Thank you.